# Reordering a paired variable

Tags: r, sorting, matrix

I was wondering about the following thing:

I have a 16x2 matrix with in the first column numerical values and in the second column also numerical values but actually they're position numbers so they need to be treated as a factor.

I want to order the values from the first column from low to high but I need the numbers of the second column to stay with their original partner value from the first column.

So let's say you've got:

```
4 1
6 2 
2 3
```

And now I want to sort the first column from low to high.

Then I want to get

```
2 3
4 1
6 2
```

Does anybody know how I can do this?

R doesn't seem to provide a variable type for paired data...

Comment: side comment: In case you want to use many column types you should use a `data.frame` not a `matrix` ( which by definition it holds one single type)

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
dat[order(dat[, 1]), ]
```